# How to decrypt message on privnote?

Tags: go, base64, aes, md5

I am looking for a solution to decrypt message (AJAX query) for privnote.com I tried to rewrite algorithm on [Python](https://github.com/intelligentguy/pyPrivnote) to [Golang](http://tpcg.io/VWlWMa). 
I am facing a problem with the key size on Golang: panic: crypto/des: invalid key size 32. How can this problem be solved?

P.S: I could not load code on SO (error: “It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details”). I am sorry

Comment: Add part of code which is relevant so that you can add the code.

Comment: but, there all the code relates to this issue ...

Comment: @AJ, In post - link on golang code. (hyperlink)

Comment: Redirecting to http://%20http//tpcg.io/VWlWMa

Comment: Oh, thk. Update post

Answer (score 1):

The key size of 32 that is mentioned in the error is set by `result[0 : 4*8]` in the return statement of the openSSLKey function.

```
func openSSLKey(password []byte, salt []byte) (string, string) {
    fmt.Println("openSSLKey | password: ", password, " | len(password): ", len(password), " | salt: ", salt, " | len(salt): ", len(salt))
    pass_salt := string(password) + string(salt)
    result := MD5(pass_salt)
    cur_hash := MD5(pass_salt)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        cur_hash := MD5(cur_hash + pass_salt)
        result += cur_hash
    }
    fmt.Println("openSSLKey | result: ", result, " len(result): ", len(result))
    return result[0 : 4*8], result[4*8 : 4*8+16]
}
```

This key is being passed to the DesDecryption function:

```
dst, err_decrypt := DesDecryption([]byte(key), []byte(iv), []byte(crypt_bytes))
```

Which then is passed to crypto/des:

```
block, err := des.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

The error is caused because the required size of the key is 8 but a key of size 32 is passed.  The required size of 8 was determined by looking at the source code for [crypto/des/cipher.go](https://golang.org/src/crypto/des/cipher.go#L30):

```
// NewCipher creates and returns a new cipher.Block.
func NewCipher(key []byte) (cipher.Block, error) {
    if len(key) != 8 {
        return nil, KeySizeError(len(key))
    }

    c := new(desCipher)
    c.generateSubkeys(key)
    return c, nil
}
```

You should be using [crypto/aes](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/aes/), which allows for a key size of 32 `The key argument should be the AES key, either 16, 24, or 32 bytes to select AES-128, AES-192, or AES-256`, like is being used in the [python code you are referring to](https://github.com/intelligentguy/pyPrivnote/blob/master/pyPrivnote/crypt.py#L48,L52):

```
pbe = openSSLkey(password, salt)
key = pbe["key"]
iv = pbe["iv"]

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv, use_aesni=True)
```